# Hosting a DNS server (e.g. bind9)

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

Hello I am a beginner with networking. I have some questions and I hope you can answer me or give some pointers, so I can learn how to do this:

I have my server at home with one real static IP. Using *bind9* with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server, I configured my `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` like this:

```
{
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        allow-query  {any;  };
        recursion yes;
}
```

Then I created a db file for my domain config:

```
$TTL 1d
$ORIGIN csgosyria.net.

@       IN      SOA     ns1     root    (
                20180904        ;Serial
                12h             ;Refresh
                15m             ;Retry
                3w              ;Expire
                2h              ;Minimum
        )

@       IN      A       my static ip

@       IN      NS      ns1
ns1     IN      A       my static ip


www     IN      A       my static ip
```

Then I added these lines to (`named.conf.options`):

```
zone "csgosyria.net" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/cache/bind/db.csgosyria.net";
};
```

For now it looks fine with me. I saved all files and restarted *bind9*. Its works without any error; but the problem is: When I type `csgosyria.net` in my browser, it says that server IP address could not be found.

On my client PC which is running Windows 10, I change my DNS from control panel to my static IP. Then, I retype my domain and it works fine.

How I can resolve this problem? I want to make my domain work without putting my IP in client PC (like I type apnic.net).

Should I register my DNS in somewhere?

Is there some port or protocol I should use?

Is there any service I should install to my Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a simple `whois csgosyria.net` command reveals that this domain is not currently registered. If you want your domain to be publicly accessed from the Internet, you need to:

1. Register your domain with a "**registrar**". You will have to pay for it. (Typically 12 USD / year for some extensions like `.com` or `.net`. However, there are some free domain extensions like `.tk`.)
2. On your registrar's *control panel* point your domain's DNS server(s) to your public static Internet IP. Normally at least two different DNS servers (IPs) are needed, but you can go with one IP only.
3. Make your DNS server's TCP and UDP ports (53) accessible from the Internet.

Comment: can i make a domain register at my server in home instead of buy it from any company like godaddy

Comment: If you want to make use of a "domain" only in your LAN, you don't have to buy it. However, **all** devices in your local network that need to use this "local domain name" need to make **all** their queries to your local DNS server on your LAN (as you have described in your question) and this DNS server should answer queries about your "local domain" as well as the other "normal" Internet domains. (So, your local DNS server should act as a "DNS forwarder" also).

Comment: For introductory information about **Domain Registration** you can look at the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_registration

Comment: so i understand from you i cant make my own domain name register using my home dns server , so there is no way to make my home dns resolve from any city in world

Comment: Yes. But, note that there are some "free domains" that you can use. For example, http://www.dot.tk/

Comment: Thanks for help me I thought i can make my own domain register using servers